# How to get the newly-installed version within a Debian postinst script?

Tags: shell, debian, package

Per the [Debian Policy Manual](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-maintainerscripts.html), my postinst script is getting called at upgrade and configure time, as "postinst configure *old-version*", where *old-version* is the previously installed version (possibly null).  I want to determine *new-version*, i.e. the version that is currently being configured (upgraded to).

The environment variable `$DPKG_MAINTSCRIPT_PACKAGE` contains the package name; there does not seem to be an equivalent `_VERSION` field.  `/var/lib/dpkg/status` gets updated AFTER postinst runs, so I can't seem to parse it out of there, either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

This is the best method I have found to resolve this issue is to use a place-holder variable in your `.postinst` (or other control files):

```
case "$1" in
    configure)
        new_version="__NEW_VERSION__"
        # Do something interesting interesting with $new_version...
        ;;
    abort-upgrade|abort-remove|abort-deconfigure)
        # Do nothing
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Unrecognized postinst argument '$1'"
        ;;
esac
```

Then in `debian/rules`, replace the placeholder variable with the proper version number at build time:

```
# Must not depend on anything. This is to be called by
# binary-arch/binary-indep in another 'make' thread.
binary-common:
    dh_testdir
    dh_testroot
    dh_lintian
    < ... snip ... >

    # Replace __NEW_VERSION__ with the actual new version in any control files
    for pkg in $$(dh_listpackages -i); do \
        sed -i -e 's/__NEW_VERSION__/$(shell $(SHELL) debian/gen_deb_version)/' debian/$$pkg/DEBIAN/*; \
    done

    # Note dh_builddeb *must* come after the above code
    dh_builddeb
```

The resulting `.postinst` snippet, found in `debian/<package-name>/DEBIAN/postinst`, will look like:

```
case "$1" in
    configure)
        new_version="1.2.3"
        # Do something interesting interesting with $new_version...
        ;;
    abort-upgrade|abort-remove|abort-deconfigure)
        # Do nothing
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Unrecognized postinst argument '$1'"
        ;;
esac
```

Comment: For a Python distutils package I needed to add the version to the postinst. I added a hook in setup.py to search-and-replace through the postinst file during the build phase.

Answer (score 4):

```
VERSION=$(zless /usr/share/doc/$DPKG_MAINTSCRIPT_PACKAGE/changelog* \
     | dpkg-parsechangelog -l- -SVersion')
```

Advantages over other solutions here:

- Works regardless of whether changelog is compressed or not
- Uses dpkg's changelog parser instead of regular expressions, awk, etc.

Comment: Nice, but that requires a added dependency to `dpkg-dev` in your package. (and you have a `}'` too much in your example I think)

Answer (score 4):

By the time postinst is run, all the package files have been installed and dpkg's data base has been updated, so you can get the just installed version with:

```
dpkg-query --show --showformat='${Version}' packagename
```

Answer (score 3):

I use the following somewhat dirty command in the postinst script:

```
NewVersion=$(zcat /usr/share/doc/$DPKG_MAINTSCRIPT_PACKAGE/changelog.gz | \
  head -1 | perl -ne '$_=~ /.*\((.*)\).*/; print $1;')
```

Comment: ugly, but it works for me.  They sure don't make it easy to do something that should be straightforward, do they!

Comment: This also fails for ~ versions that are not reflected in the changelog.

Answer (score 3):

Add the following to the `debian/rules`:

```
override_dh_installdeb:
    dh_installdeb
    for pkg in $$(dh_listpackages -i); do \
        sed -i -e 's/__DEB_VERSION__/$(DEB_VERSION)/' debian/$$pkg/DEBIAN/*; \
    done
```

It will replace any occurrence of `__DEB_VERSION__` in your debian scripts with the version number.

Comment: `$(DEB_VERSION)` doesn't seem to work anymore.  You can replace it in the code snippet above with `$(shell dpkg-parsechangelog --count 1 -S version)`

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you hard-code the version into the postinst script at packaging time?

Comment: Hardcoding this in a script needs changing it every time... Not that good of an idea in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
VERSION=`dpkg -s $DPKG_MAINTSCRIPT_PACKAGE | sed -n 's/^Version: //p'`
```